# specify a root in igraph minimum-spanning-tree

Tags: r, tree, igraph, directed-graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a weighted adjacency matrix and I need to create a directed MST.  The problem is that I know the edge weights and the root, so I can generate an MST on an undirected graph, but I cant find a way to then specify a root.  If I could specify a root, this would automatically induce directions on all the edges of the MST, completing the task.

```
my_graph <- igraph::graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adjmatrix = cluster_adj_matrix, mode = "upper", weighted = TRUE)
my_mst <- igraph::mst(my_graph)
```

Answer (score 0):

The two main features I was interested in: path length to root and predecessor of the directed graph can be generated in the following way:

To get predecessors:

```
GetPredecessors <- function(minspantree, root){
  pathdata <- igraph::get.shortest.paths(graph = minspantree, from = root)
  pathlist <- prelist <- lapply(paths$vpath, function(x){
    y = as.vector(x)
    y[(length(y)-1)]
  })
  prelist[[root]] <- 0
  return(unlist(prelist))
}
```

To get the path lengths to the root:

```
igraph::shortest.paths(graph = minspantree, v = root)
```